# FFmpeg creating mp4 becomes asynchronous

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a command which converts a .mpg file to a .mp4 file.
But somehow the mp4 files becomes asychronous the Audio has a delay of 0.5 seconds.

Any idea of how to fix this since the mpg file is synchron.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -deinterlace -r 25 -s 1024x576 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -vprofile high -b:v 1350k -minrate 1400k -maxrate 1400k -bufsize 1400k -trellis 2 -x264opts nal-hrd=cbr -acodec mp3 -ab 192k -async 1 test.mp4
```

Update

My bad the above command works properly, I have following commands which create me a m2v and mp2 file from a giving timestamp, after that I merge those 2 files to a mp4 file which becomes asynchronous.

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i fulltest.m2v -c:v copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -sn test.m2v
ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i fulltest.mp2 -c:v copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -sn test.mp2

ffmpeg -i test.m2v -i test.mp2 -target pal-dvd -vcodec copy -acodec copy fulltest.mpg

ffmpeg -i fulltest.mpg -deinterlace -r 25 -s 1024x576 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -vprofile high -b:v 1350k -minrate 1400k -maxrate 1400k -bufsize 1400k -trellis 2 -x264opts nal-hrd=cbr -acodec mp3 -ab 192k fulltest.mp4
```

Comment: What happens without `-async 1`?

Comment: @Mulvya sorry for the late Response, it still becomes aysnchronous, I once added -async 1 because I read that it may solve my problem

Comment: Show full log of command, and also output of `ffprobe -show_streams -of compact test.mpg`

Comment: @Mulvya hi sorry again for the late Response I run the command above and it works the mistake I make happens if I run this commands `ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i fulltest.m2v -c:v copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -sn test.m2v
ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i fulltest.mp2 -c:v copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -sn test.mp2

` I updated my question

Comment: @Mulvya any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 30 -i fulltest.m2v -ss 0 -t 30 -i fulltest.mp2
       -vf yadif,scale=1024:576,format=yuv420p -r 25
       -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -vprofile high -b:v 1350k -minrate 1400k -maxrate 1400k -bufsize 1400k
       -trellis 2 -x264opts nal-hrd=cbr
       -acodec mp3 -ab 192k   fulltest.mp4
```

You can skip the temporary files. `-t` option is duration, not `-to` endpoint. So, calculate the duration e.g. from 10s to 17s is 7 seconds.

---

To keep the temporary files,

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i fulltest.m2v -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -vf yadif,scale=1024:576,format=yuv420p -r 25
       -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -vprofile high -b:v 1350k -minrate 1400k -maxrate 1400k -bufsize 1400k
       -trellis 2 -x264opts nal-hrd=cbr
       -an -sn tempvideo.mp4

ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i fulltest.mp2 -c:a copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -sn tempaudio.mp2

ffmpeg -i tempvideo.mp4 -i tempaudio.mp2 -c:v copy -c:a mp3 -b:a 192k fulltest.mp4
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I did not try it yet, so what excatly did I make wrong. Could you Show me the command like I did the temporary files have a further use for me.

Comment: When you use `-c:v copy` with a time range, the output may not be the range you requested since videos can only be cut on keyframes. Since, in your set of commands, you are ultimately re-encoding the streams, I skipped the intermediate steps.

Comment: Would it be possible to Change These commands `ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i fulltest.m2v -c:v copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -sn test.m2v ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i fulltest.mp2 -c:v copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -sn test.mp2` so that it becomes synchron, I Need to timecodes in my case

Comment: Thanks I am going to try it out

Comment: A quick question if I do this: `ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i fulltest.mp2 -c:a copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -sn tempaudio.mp2` I Need to use -c:a copy to copy the Audio I guess what do I have to do if I want to do this with a m2v `ffmpeg -v quiet -y -i fulltest.mp2 -c:a copy -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:30 -sn tempaudio.mp2` -c:v copy for Video ?

Comment: Hi so it somehow worked and somehow did not, I am running These commands 4 times to divide a movie into 4 pieces, the first run is synchron but the others are not any idea?

Comment: Run all your commands with -report added and share the report.